Evap canister removal and replacement on a 2007 saturn aura
Is there a easy way the remove and  replace the evap canister  on a 2007 saturn aura with out removing the fuel tank

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Does this help? At end of video, describing evap canister, passenger side, in front of gas tank; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3zad-5TMjI
